# I don't understand the "rational" arguments for trig functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, definition

For example look at $\cos(x)$. I imagine that $x$ can sometimes be rational (or integer) or irrational, and sometimes $\cos(x)$ can be rational (or integer), or irrational.

Under what circumstances is $\cos(x)$ rational (or integer), or irrational, and under which combinations of rational/integer/irrational inputs $x$ can these arise?

In other words what are the relationships?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if as usual we use radian measure, the only rational value of $\cos x$ at rational $x$ is at $x=0$. Ivan Niven has given a quite accessible proof.

Integer values are much more obvious. The only integer $x$ for which $\cos x$ is an integer is $x=0$.

As to for which **irrational** $x$ we have $\cos x$ rational, probably not much can be said in general. For example, the good old $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle gives us a couple of rational cosines, but there is no nice independent description of the corresponding angles.

One can describe completely the $x$ of shape $x=r\pi$, where $r$ is  rational,  such that $\cos x$ is rational. Equivalently, we have complete information about the cosine of angles that are rational when *measured in degrees*.

It turns out that one can prove that the only rational multiples of $\pi$ whose cosine is rational are the ones we can easily think of: the integer multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and the $x$ of shape $\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi$ and $\pm \frac{2\pi}{3}+2n\pi$.

**Remark:** The results mentioned above can be found in Niven's *Rational and Irrational Numbers*. If you do not have ready access to the book, googling rational values of trigonometric functions niven gives a fair number of hits.

Comment: Lindemann-Weiestrass gives the result about $\cos(0)$ and more: $\cos(x)$ is transcendental for any nonzero algebraic $x$.

Comment: Yes, $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are simultaneously rational for infinitely many $x$. This is the same result as the result that there are infinitely many "really different" Pythagorean triples, that is, triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$. The system  does not like long strings of comments. So I will delete most of mine, and suggest you do the same. This will leave comment space if you have any other related questions. But for anything substantially different, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: "the good old 3-4-5 triangle gives us a couple of rational cosines, but there is no nice independent description of the corresponding angles." Is there a proof of the latter statement somewhere, maybe somewhere in Ivan Niven's books?